# What different areas can you spawn in PUBG?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

A few weeks ago, PUBG updated, and now you are not always spawning on the island/prison, but at a selection of locations.

What different locations can you get in both maps, and about how much players spawn at each location?

Comment: May I ask why you are asking this? Where you spawn is irrelevant

Comment: The thrist for knowledge I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On Erangel:

- Zharki
- Stalber
- Blue Warehouse West of Prison
- Military Base North-West of Observatory
- The original Spawn Island in the North-East portion of the map
- Quarry

On Miramar:

- The Prison
- The Graveyard
- [Southeast of El Azahar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9j1U.png)
- Ruins
- Mines south of Los Leones
- Island east of Impala
- Junkyard

On Sanhok:

- Na Kham
- Docks
- Paradise Resort
- Lakawi
- [Ruins east of Camp Alpha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAfbe.png)

(Additional locations needed)